# angular-ui-calendar : events are not displayed in the calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

the events are not displayed on the calendar , many examples on the web were similar to this , but still it isn't working

i have included the css and js files of fullcalendar

this is my index.html

```html
<div class="container">
<div style="width:60%;" ui-calendar='$ctrl.uiConfig.calendar' ng-model="$ctrl.eventSources">
 
</div>
</div>
```

this is my controller.js file

```js
'use strict';
(function(){

class CalendarComponent {
  constructor() {

    this.uiConfig = {
       calendar : {
              editable : true,
              header : {
                        left : 'prev,next,today',
                        center : 'title',
                        right : 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                       }
                  }
                };
       
    this.thespian_events= [      
                         events: [
                               {title: "finger painting", start: "2016-07-26T10:06:30+05:30", allDay:true}
                               ],

                           color: 'blue'
                      ];              
   
    this.eventSources = [this.thespian_events];
               
  } 

 } 

angular.module('sangamApp')
  .component('calendar', {
    templateUrl: 'app/calendar/calendar.html',
    controller: CalendarComponent
  });

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

events is an array of objects. Try to initialize it like so:

```
this.thespian_events = [
    {title: "finger painting", start: "2016-07-26T10:06:30+05:30", allDay:true}
    {title: "other event", start: "2016-08-26T10:06:30+05:30", allDay:true}
];
```

eventSource is an object, declare like this:

```
this.eventSources = { events: this.thespian_events };
```

For the color, use a css class instead with the className property:

```
this.thespian_events = [
    {title: "finger painting", start: "2016-07-26T10:06:30+05:30", allDay:true, className: 'finger-painting'}
    {title: "other event", start: "2016-08-26T10:06:30+05:30", allDay:true, className: 'default-event'}
];
```

And a css example:

```
.default-event > div {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
}
.default-event > div :hover {
    color: black;
}
```